Does whose turn is next impact material advantage?
My second grader is preparing for the UIL Chess Puzzle Solving competition in January and I've been reviewing the question types to help him and his club prepare. These tests contain 20 multiple choice questions designed to assess the kids' knowledge of the rules and strategies of chess.
One of the question types is about material advantage. The guidance when preparing for this test is to memorize the piece values so you can look at a board example and answer the question, "Which side has material advantage?" This seems simple enough, so I'm not overly concerned with three of the possible answers ("White", "Black", "It's even") but the fourth answer choice in all of the sample tests I've seen is, "It's not possible to tell without knowing who is to move."
On first thought, it seems like the test taking strategy for us to teach the kids is to never choose that last answer, even if they've managed to forget the values of the pieces but I'm curious whether that's actually true. The last thing I want to teach them is that move order doesn't matter if it does.
While most of the puzzles indicate whose move is next, these sorts of questions do not. Here's two of the sample questions from the 2018-2019 test for reference (source), one of this type (#4), one of another type (#3).

While I understand there's more depth to material advantage than piece value alone, is it likely safe for them to disregard the last option? In what situations might knowing who plays next be important?

I think #4 is a case of needing four options (A, B, C, D) and there are only three obvious ones (either x > y, x = y, or x < y) so you gotta come up with something for option D, even if it's silly.

Sure. I'm willing to accept that as an explanation and had considered it already. That said, because who's to move can factor into the overall advantage of the game, it seems like the puzzles would have to be carefully designed to avoid situations where the next move could drastically flip the balance of the game (without being a horrible move).

It perhaps depends on how strict your definitions are. Consider the following position:
[fen "rnb1kbnr/pp1ppppp/8/q1p5/Q1P5/8/PP1PPPPP/RNB1KBNR w KQkq - 2 3"]

Although, technically, material is even for the moment, the side to move is about to realize a large material advantage. It would be folly to analyze the position without this being the primary consideration. As an even more extreme example, if White played Qxd7+ here, White would then be up a pawn and therefore technically have a material advantage, but Black must retake, so that "advantage" is illusory.
I am guessing that the tests will not contain such a question in this context, however, as it would be rather unfair to the students.

I've been looking through a lot of the sample problems of this type and it's led me to believe that they likely (?) design the game state for these puzzles such that a single move is unlikely to change the balance of the game. For example, if white is behind in points, they either can't possibly capture anything that would change the  advantage (e.g. they're 2 points behind and can only capture pawns) or, if they did, they'd likely lose as many points when black played again (e.g. they take a rook but then black can take their queen).
